# "Order Code" vs "Ordering Code"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, grammar, word-usage

**In short:** What would be more appropriate for labelling the column header of a table listing products?

In a table listing multiple products, what term would be more appropriate for labelling the column with the codes referring to the products?

Sample code of a  product: "**AE02KR123**"
When the client wants to order a product, all he needs to provide is the code "AE02KR123"

```
• Order Code
• Ordering Code
• Code
• [something else ?]
```

Answer (score 2):

The terminology most often using in stockkeeping or webshops for an identifying product code is **SKU** (StockKeeping Unit).

[Wiki link here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit)

More often than not, the SKU is composed based on a product's properties, e.g. SKU "TRL" could just be "T-shirt, Red, Large". This assumes that you're only selling one product that fits that description.
You could just as well use a generic numbering scheme where the item's traits are irrelevant.

Internally, it's called an SKU. To the customer, it's often called a Product Code.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it seems like "Product Code" (or just "Code" if there's no ambiguity) would be appropriate.  "Order Code" would be a code associated to a specific order, not a specific product.

Answer (score 0):

You want a label for the column where the codes to order products apprear then call it `Codes to order`.